# Nested CASE WHEN statement within a calculation under the THEN or ELSE clause

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, nested, case

I am transferring a current Microsoft Access process to SQL SERVER 2016 and I am having an issue with re-writing one of the Access SQL queries. The current Access query has the following code within the set function

```
b.New_AVM_Index = IIf(a.[AVM_Index]>0
                 ,a.[AVM_Index]*(IIf(a.[Stratified_Median_AVM]>0
                 ,IIf(b.[Stratified_Median_AVM]>0
                 ,b.[Stratified_Median_AVM]/a.[Stratified_Median_AVM]
                 ,1),1)),10000)
```

The IIf Access function works much in the same as SQL CASE WHEN statement, **but my question is what is the best way to handle nested case when statements within a calculation under the THEN clause or the ELSE clause in SQL SERVER?**

Below is my attempt at adding the New_AVM_Index column to a table without success:

```
CASE WHEN (a.[AVM_Index]>0
                 THEN a.[AVM_Index]* (WHEN(a.[Stratified_Median_AVM]>0
                 THEN WHEN (b.[Stratified_Median_AVM]>0
                 THEN b.[Stratified_Median_AVM]/a.[Stratified_Median_AVM]
                 ELSE 1 END) ELSE 1 END)) ELSE 10000)
                 END AS New_AVM_Index
```

I have reviewed the other nested case when questions, however I have not seen an example of a nested case when statement within a calculation.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` inside of a `CASE`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.[AVM_Index] > 0 
        THEN a.[AVM_Index] * (CASE WHEN a.[Stratified_Median_AVM] > 0
                                THEN (CASE WHEN b.[Stratified_Median_AVM] > 0
                                            THEN b.[Stratified_Median_AVM] / a.[Stratified_Median_AVM]
                                            ELSE 1 END
                                     ) 
                                ELSE 1 END)
    ELSE 10000
    END AS New_AVM_Index
```

Comment: @da4l glad I could help.